# JavaScript callback/closure/other

Tags: javascript, callback

I have the below piece of code:

```
$("some_html_stuff").insertAfter('.some_element');
```

I then have other JS code which I need to be sure will execute AFTER the insertAfter function has finished its business. How can a achieve this? I looked at closures and a bunch of other stuff, but I don't seem to be able to figure this out.

Comment: If you're having an issue in your code, perhaps you should explain it. You seem to have assumed the cause of an issue, and are therefore asking about the assumed cause instead. [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I did indeed assume that my code wasn't working as expected because I automatically assumed that insertAfter is async. It's all cleared up now, code is working nicely. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a synchronous command. Nothing further will execute until it's finished.

```
$("some_html_stuff").insertAfter('.some_element');
// Do something after
```

Answer (score 1):

`.insertAfter` is not asynchronous, so just add your other code right after that line of code.